# Error: JavaScript countdown timer does not countdown

Tags: javascript, timer, dom-events, countdown

I am trying to build a countdown timer which countdowns between two given time.

I want my timer to countdown the time between June 19, 2014 12:20:00 &
June 16, 2014 12:00:00

But it does not countdown. It remains static as itself.

```
function timer()
{
    var now = new Date("June 16, 2014 12:00:00");
    var enddate = new Date("June 19, 2014 12:20:00");
    var totalRemains = (enddate.getTime()-now.getTime());
    if (totalRemains>1)
    {
        var RemainsSec=(parseInt(totalRemains/1000));
        var RemainsFullDays=(parseInt(RemainsSec/(24*60*60)));
        var secInLastDay=RemainsSec-RemainsFullDays*24*3600;
        var RemainsFullHours=(parseInt(secInLastDay/3600));
        if (RemainsFullHours<10){RemainsFullHours="0"+RemainsFullHours};
        var secInLastHour=secInLastDay-RemainsFullHours*3600;
        var RemainsMinutes=(parseInt(secInLastHour/60));
        if (RemainsMinutes<10){RemainsMinutes="0"+RemainsMinutes};
        var lastSec=secInLastHour-RemainsMinutes*60;
        if (lastSec<10){lastSec="0"+lastSec};
        var mcend = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2012, 00:00:00");
        var mcnow = now.getTime();
        var mc = ((mcend-mcnow)/10).toFixed(0).substr(8);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: '+ RemainsFullHours+":"+RemainsMinutes+":"+lastSec+'</p>';
        setTimeout(timer,10);
    } 
    else {document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: 00:00:00</p>';}
}
                                 timer();
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bVCMe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t1 = new Date("June 14, 2014, 12:40:00") //end date
var t2 = new Date("June 14, 2014, 00:00:01") //initial date
var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs((t1.getTime() - t2.getTime()) / 1000);
timer(Seconds_Between_Dates);

function timer(Seconds_Between_Dates) {
if (Seconds_Between_Dates > 1) {
    var RemainDays = (parseInt(Seconds_Between_Dates / (24 * 60 * 60)));
    var lastDaySecs = Seconds_Between_Dates - RemainDays * 24 * 3600;
    var RemainsFullHours = (parseInt(lastDaySecs / 3600));
    if (RemainsFullHours < 10) {
        RemainsFullHours = "0" + RemainsFullHours
    };
    var secInLastHour = lastDaySecs - RemainsFullHours * 3600;
    var RemainsMinutes = (parseInt(secInLastHour / 60));
    if (RemainsMinutes < 10) {
        RemainsMinutes = "0" + RemainsMinutes
    };
       var lastSec = secInLastHour - RemainsMinutes * 60;
       if (lastSec < 10) {
        lastSec = "0" + lastSec
    };
       document.getElementById('effect').innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: ' + RemainDays + ":::::" + RemainsFullHours + ":" + RemainsMinutes + ":" + lastSec + '</p>';
    Seconds_Between_Dates = Seconds_Between_Dates - 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        timer(Seconds_Between_Dates)
    }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/bVCMe/9/

Comment: This is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var enddate = new Date("June 19, 2014 12:20:00");
timer();

function timer() {
var now = new Date();
var totalRemains = (enddate.getTime() - now.getTime());
if (totalRemains > 1) {
    var RemainsSec = (parseInt(totalRemains / 1000));
    var RemainsFullDays = (parseInt(RemainsSec / (24 * 60 * 60)));
    var secInLastDay = RemainsSec - RemainsFullDays * 24 * 3600;
    var RemainsFullHours = (parseInt(secInLastDay / 3600));
    if (RemainsFullHours < 10) {
        RemainsFullHours = "0" + RemainsFullHours
    };
    var secInLastHour = secInLastDay - RemainsFullHours * 3600;
    var RemainsMinutes = (parseInt(secInLastHour / 60));
    if (RemainsMinutes < 10) {
        RemainsMinutes = "0" + RemainsMinutes
    };
    var lastSec = secInLastHour - RemainsMinutes * 60;
    if (lastSec < 10) {
        lastSec = "0" + lastSec
    };
    var mcend = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2012, 00:00:00");
    var mcnow = now.getTime();
    var mc = ((mcend - mcnow) / 10).toFixed(0).substr(8);
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: ' + RemainsFullHours + ":" + RemainsMinutes + ":" + lastSec + '</p>';
    setTimeout(timer, 10);
} else {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: 00:00:00</p>';
}
}
```

Comment: Come on Dude! That's not what I am looking for. Your solution countdowns from June 19, 2014 12:20:00 to current time. I am looking for a countdown timer to countdown b/w June 19, 2014 12:20:00 & lets say June 16, 2014 12:00:00 or any other date. Please read the question carefully. @saurabh bade

Answer (score -1):

```
var enddate = new Date("June 19, 2014 12:20:00");
timer();

function timer() {
var now = new Date();
var totalRemains = (enddate.getTime() - now.getTime());
if (totalRemains > 1) {
    var RemainsSec = (parseInt(totalRemains / 1000));
    var RemainsFullDays = (parseInt(RemainsSec / (24 * 60 * 60)));
    var secInLastDay = RemainsSec - RemainsFullDays * 24 * 3600;
    var RemainsFullHours = (parseInt(secInLastDay / 3600));
    if (RemainsFullHours < 10) {
        RemainsFullHours = "0" + RemainsFullHours
    };
    var secInLastHour = secInLastDay - RemainsFullHours * 3600;
    var RemainsMinutes = (parseInt(secInLastHour / 60));
    if (RemainsMinutes < 10) {
        RemainsMinutes = "0" + RemainsMinutes
    };
    var lastSec = secInLastHour - RemainsMinutes * 60;
    if (lastSec < 10) {
        lastSec = "0" + lastSec
    };
    var mcend = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2012, 00:00:00");
    var mcnow = now.getTime();
    var mc = ((mcend - mcnow) / 10).toFixed(0).substr(8);
    document.getElementById('effect').innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: ' + RemainsFullHours + ":" + RemainsMinutes + ":" + lastSec + '</p>';
    setTimeout(timer, 10);
} else {
    document.getElementById("effect").innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: 00:00:00</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: A block of code with no explanation what was wrong and what changed does not constitute a good answer. Please edit your post.

Comment: Only current date was needed to be changed each time when timer function is called.

Comment: And it does not produce any results either. @saurabh bade

Comment: what is happening?why its not working...may be element with id(effect) is not present in html dom